# .htaccess File Options -Indexes on Subdirectories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2

I have the following .htaccess line, simple no indexes on root.

```
Options -Indexes
```

What do we add so it propagates to any sub directory instead of having to create one file for each? One .htaccess on root only.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The correct answer is

```
Options -Indexes
```

You must have been thinking of

```
AllowOverride All
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html

> .htaccess files (or "distributed configuration files") provide a way
>   to make configuration changes on a per-directory basis. A file,
>   containing one or more configuration directives, is placed in a
>   particular document directory, and the directives apply to that
>   directory, and all subdirectories thereof.

Comment: It's `AllowOverride All`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I have removed my old answer to this 7 year old question.

Answer (score 30):

> htaccess files affect the directory
>   they are placed in and all
>   sub-directories, that is an htaccess
>   file located in your root directory
>   (yoursite.com) would affect
>   yoursite.com/content,
>   yoursite.com/content/contents, etc.

http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess.shtml

Comment: Actually it does, just tested it. Even without ALL it applies to sub folders!

Comment: @Codex73, Kaleb is right: .htaccess ["directives apply to that directory, and all subdirectories"](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#what).