# Single Htaccess to stop access of all directories

Tags: php, .htaccess

My Directory structure is like this.

```
    Root
      |
    assets
     |-js
     |-css
     |-img
    action
      |a.php
      |-b.php
    include
      |-inc1.php
      |-inc2.php
```

I'm using Option `Options -Indexes`  in .htaccess file but i have to put this file in every directory. Is there a way i can use only one hraccess file and put rule on directories? Also i wanted to know .If i use htaccess will it stop my php file from accessing the resources from these directories?

Comment: It did not work when put in the .htaccess file of the root?

Comment: @AlexisWilke giving an error ->Internal Server Error

Comment: There is a similar question here though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767785/htaccess-file-options-indexes-on-subdirectories

Comment: @AlexisWilke Can u pls tell me the answer of question i asked Lloyd in his answer's comment

Comment: `Options -Indexes` in the root .htaccess affects all the sub directories under it.

Comment: @anubhava does it affect script execution in any way like stop php script from accessing these files?

Comment: No it doesn't. It just prevents visitors to list directory contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal uses this in the root directory to prevent client access to some files. "profile" and "module" are directories. [Correction: profile and module are directories, but in the Drupal expression below it is checked as an extension.]

```
# Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl|svn-base)$|^(code-style\.pl|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template|all-wcprops|entries|format|LICENSE.txt)$">
  Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>
```

For you you'd want to change the matching rule to something like this:

```
<FilesMatch "^(assets|action|include)$">
```

Answer (score 1):

It's normal to use just one .htacces file in the root directory. If you want to apply rules to particular directories without adding another .htaccess file, you may be able to apply rules based on the url if the url maps with the folders. It would be easier to help you if you provided a concrete example

Comment: Hey tnx, dnt want any rules just prevent access to these folders. Will htaccess affect the functioning of the scripts? or will it just deny access if directory is accessed manually