# How can I check in php if index.php exists in every subdirectories

Tags: php, html

Is there a way to check if index.php exists in my subdirectories ?

For instance :

```
home/
|__folder/
|  |__index.php
|  |__style.css
|
|__folder2/
|  |__style.css
|
|__folder3/
   |__text.txt
```

I want to check if there is a index.php in folder, folder2, folder3.
Eventually, I should create index.php if it doesn't exist.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Take a look at is_file,is_dir,glob and examples of recursive glob functions on the doc page: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Comment: I'm sure you could write a bash script to do this for you, although could you explain why you want to do this? It sounds like you should just disable directory indexes on your web server.

Comment: As @nullability says, you'd properly be better of editing your webserver config, or use .htaccess if using a shared host. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767785/htaccess-file-options-indexes-on-subdirectories

Comment: you would want to make a `.htaccess` with `Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes` so users can't see your files

Comment: I tried with scandir but i don't know if there is a better or faster way. I want to generate a same default homepage for each folder if there is no current index.php.

Comment: Okay, what problem are you trying to solve by putting `index.php` everywhere?

Comment: By the way, this approach keeping folders secure is old-fashioned and outdated. People were using it in 2002-2008

Comment: sure. get a list of your subdirectories, iterate over them, and check for index.php in each.

Comment: Yeah i know, this is not what i'm trying to do haha. I just want to generate the same index.php which will behave differently depending on the current directory. But first i want to check if there is a index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrote a quick class that would do this, run from command prompt/terminal.

```
class FolderChecker {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->scan_folder(getcwd());
    }

    public function scan_folder($folder) {
        $scandir = scandir($folder);

        if(file_exists($folder . "/index.php")) {
            echo "index.php file exists in $folder\n";
        } else {
            echo "index.php file DOES NOT exists in $folder\n";
        }

        foreach($scandir as $scan) {
            if($scan == "." || $scan == ".." || is_file($folder . '/' . $scan))
                continue;

            if(is_dir($folder . '/' . $scan)) 
                $this->scan_folder($folder . '/' . $scan);
        }
    }

}

new FolderChecker;
```