# I'm trying to prevent access images folder on my the website with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to prevent access images folder on my the website with .htaccess
here is my folder
http://192.168.1.55/onlineshop/images/

Comment: Can you elaborate the question?

Comment: how i can prevent access images folder on my the website

Comment: Try this post you will get the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767785/htaccess-file-options-indexes-on-subdirectories

Comment: Create .htaccess file in that folder, add this in you file 

Deny from all

Answer (score 0):

if .htaccess file is not working than you can add index.html file in your folder with content of forbidden access, while anyone open's that url than index.html file will run. So your folder is prevent from direct use.

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

create .htaccess file in images folder
i.e 
http://192.168.1.55/onlineshop/images/.htaccess
and add below code in .htaccess file

```
Deny from all
```

Answer (score 0):

Create .htaccess in that folder with the following content.

`Deny from all`

Comment: it work but , how can display a message instead of forbidden message

Comment: To show some custom message , Add this in htaccess file: ErrorDocument 403 /path/to/403.html

Comment: That will show content from that HTML file instead of the standard forbidden message.

Comment: Hi @AbdeAMNR if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.